# How do I change the default changing language hotkey 'ctrl-space' in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, input-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ctrl-Space always toggles IME (Win 7)](https://superuser.com/questions/327479/ctrl-space-always-toggles-ime-win-7)

Whenever I press 'ctrl-space' it will switch to Chinese input, I want to change this behaviour to prevent the confliction with visual studio. I tried **Advanced Key Settings -> Change Key Sequence** but it didn't work.

Comment: Probably not what you want but just in case: you can change the Visual studio keystroke by using **Tools->Options** then **Environment->Keyboard** then in the the Show commands containing type *Edit.CompleteWord*  and assign a new keystroke.

Comment: @Tod, I don't want to change VS keystroke but the window's one since I also use Eclipse, LinqPad.